# WebSphere email alert for hung threads

Tags: multithreading, websphere, hung

Other than scanning the log files for the specific WebSphere code, is there a way to setup an email alert for a WebSphere hung thread policy?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the edition and version of WebSphere Application Server (WAS) you're asking about. Prior to WAS version 8.5.5, IBM provided this capability in a separate product called WebSphere Virtual Enterprise (WVE). In version 8.5.5, this functionality was integrated into the WAS Network Deployment edition (ND) edition as Intelligent Management (IM) and Health Mgmt.  In an ND environment, you can create a health policy as described in [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twve_odhealthpolicy.html).  That policy should have a custom health condition subexpression [(as described here)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwve_hconditionsubex.html) for the PMI metric `concurrently hung threads`.  You'll also need to configure the SMTP notification for the policy ([as described here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/task_detail_main.html)).  If you're using what is sometimes colloquially referred to as base edition of WAS, it doesn't provide any notification beyond logging.